# Meta-SE discussion about "unpinning" accepted answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We should probably weigh in on [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?cb=1) that's looking for input from the component SE sites. The proposal is to no longer "pin" the accepted answer to be the first displayed, and their looking for feedback about essentially "opting in" or out.

Comment: Just for information: [Update 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/369568/6) on the linked Meta SE post says that the default option—that is, to keep the accepted answer pinned—will not be changed for any site across the network, unless a particular site specifically requests that the option be changed based on a discussion on their local meta.

Answer (score 5):

And I'll go ahead and cast my vote that I think it's a great idea and they should make it "roll out the change to all sites by default except those that opt out."

Comment: If even Math voted for unpinning, where the merits of answer should be easiest to compare, I see no reason to keep pinning in music.

Answer (score 1):

If we have the option of opting out and keeping accepted answers pinned, I am in favor of opting out. My experience with our site is that in general we're better served by keeping accepted answers pinned.

Comment: I take that link to mean that Stack *Overflow* has made its choice, but the meta discussion I posted mentions "triaging these requests [in] mid-to-late October." Not clear to me whether it's still open to input until then.
It's not really a big deal on our site, where most questions get few answers and the accepted one is typically also the highest-voted. There are many cases on SO though of "somebody accepted an answer hastily, but it was wrong, incomplete, or is now outdated, and the better answer with 100x the votes is buried below it."

Comment: Or maybe I'm just biased by my "48 to -13" experience: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295767/how-to-refer-to-particular-years-in-a-specific-century-in-one-expression

Comment: @AndyBonner That may be the most extreme instance of this I've ever seen. Wow!

Comment: You're correct about Stack Overflow; I've removed the reference. And I agree that the pinning can and does go wrong — 48 to -13 notwithstanding! (sheesh!) — but while I do find the exceptions on our site very, very annoying, I do think in general we're well served by pinning.